# Add HTML Around Regex Matches From Element Inner Text

Tags: javascript

I have a span element with a piece of inner text. I need to target specific pieces of that text through regex and turn my matches into span elements with a class attribute class="hightlight-yellow" and a custom attribute called my-custom-attribute="hello".

Here is my input and expected output...

**Input**

```
<span class="message"> This is some text $HIGH:LOW $LOW:HIGH </span>
```

**Output**

```
<span> This is some text <span class="highlight-yellow" my-custom-attribute="hello">$HIGH:LOW</span> <span class="highlight-yellow" my-custom-attribute="hello">$LOW:HIGH</span></span>
```

How can I do the replace? Here is my current code colleting the matches

```
   function handle()
{
    let element = document.getElementsByClassName('message')
    let text = element[0].innerText;
    let regex = /([^=])\$([A-Za-z:]{1,})/g;
    let matches = text.match(regex);

    if(matches != null)
    {
        for(let i = 0; i < matches.length; ++i)
        {
            // TODO takes matches are replace with spans with attributes.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use your regex in [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and replace it with the desired markup wrapping your capturing group.

I have removed the first capturing group since it matches the empty whitespace before, which is not what you want. On top of that, I'd suggest using `querySelectorAll` and iterate through the node list to future proof your setup.

If you really only want to select the first element that matches the selector `.message`, that's also possible.

*NOTE: Your output also seems to remove the `message` class from your original `<span>` element, but I'm not sure if that is a typo or intentional.*

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
function handle() {
  const regex = /\$([A-Za-z:]{1,})/g;
  
  document.querySelectorAll('.message').forEach(el => {
    el.innerHTML = el.innerText.replace(regex, '<span class="highlight-yellow" my-custom-attribute="hello">$1</span>');
  });
}

handle();
```

```css
span.highlight-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<span class="message">This is some text $HIGH:LOW $LOW:HIGH</span>
```